# Processing-2.2.1 Build errors in Android Mode

Tags: android, processing

I get following error when I try a small program using **Processing-2.2.1** in Android Mode.

It works fine in Java Mode

```
BUILD FAILED
c:\SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
c:\SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Error running javac.exe compiler

Build file lines are:
build.xml:716: <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
build.xml:730: fork="${need.javac.fork}">
```

Comment: perhaps a bit more of the build.xml. Diff itself would give you more context :)

Comment: Removed greetings/salutations as per the SO ask questions rule

Comment: @vise if you run cmd.exe, type javac then hit Enter what output do you get ?